# How can i inflat layout for AlertDialog when i click item in popup menu?

Tags: java, android, alert

This my code i try to do but i don't know what the code i must added to do that.
plesae help me!
Thanks in advance :)

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull HalakaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.bind(halakat.get(position));
    holder.imgbtn_more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(holder.itemView.getContext(), view);
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.halaka_more_menu, popup.getMenu());
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
                    int id = menuItem.getItemId();
                    switch (id) {
                        case R.id.menu_more_halaka_tadel:
                            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), ""+menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            final AlertDialog.Builder alert=new AlertDialog.Builder(holder.itemView.getContext());
                            break;
                        case R.id.menu_more_halaka_delete:
                            Toast.makeText(holder.itemView.getContext(), ""+menuItem.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
            popup.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To show an AlertDialog you need to call `create()` then `show()` methods after you define its properties.
That means in your code after you define the alert variable, set the title and message then write this `alert.create().show()`

use `setView()` method and pass your layout xml as a parameter.

You can use `View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_snippet, null);` and access your child views from it like: `TextView userName = rootView.findViewById(R.id.userName);`

Comment: I creat acustom layout to view it as alret

Comment: it's work but how to inflat the items in the custom layout?